# Script to pull from multiple Git Repos and build (Maven Projects)

Tags: windows, git, maven, batch-file

I looking to create a script of some sort that can auto pull and build multiple git repos.(Windows machine)

The local git repositories are as follows:

> C:\Users\user\Git\projectA\projectA
>
> C:\Users\user\Git\projectB\projectB
>
> C:\Users\user\Git\projectC\projectC
>
> C:\Users\user\Git\projectD\projectD

In doing this it will switch to the develop branch of the contained folders:

```
So this would run something like this:
```

> cd projectA
>
> cd projectA
>
> git checkout develop
>
> mvn clean install
>
> cd..
>
> cd..

---

And so on through all the contained projects

---

> cd projectB
>
> cd projectB
>
> git checkout develop
>
> mvn clean install
>
> cd..
>
> cd..

Any guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a parenthesised loop to `cd` to each path and perform tasks, you can run the script from anywhere on the device if you specify the parent path and no need to `cd..`

```
for /D %%a in ("C:\Users\user\Git\*") do ( 
    cd "%%a"
    git checkout develop 
    mvn clean install
)
```

Based on your change in question and comments, if your child project folder will be the same name as the parent folder, then simply do:

```
for /D %%a in ("C:\Users\user\Git\*") do ( 
    cd "%%a\%%~na"
    git checkout develop 
    mvn clean install
)
```

if you have other folders in `git` other than project folders and want to only `cd` to the project ones, then:

```
for /D %%a in ("C:\Users\user\Git\project*") do ( 
    cd "%%a\%%~na"
    git checkout develop 
    mvn clean install
)
```

As for your last comment, the only way you will be able to do that really is to use a loop, but specify each of the orders in the `for` loop:

```
for %%a in (B,C,A) do ( 
    cd "C:\Users\user\Git\project%%a\project%%a"
    git checkout develop 
    mvn clean install
)
```

or even if you want to specify full folders instead, if they might have different names, as example:

```
for %%a in (projectB,NewProjectC,AnotherProjectA) do ( 
    cd "C:\Users\user\Git\%%a\%%a"
    git checkout develop 
    mvn clean install
)
```

The problem with these are that it will be very large for loops if you have many projects to run with.

Comment: I like your approach, however I needed to update the question to reflect the existing file directory format....git files are one folder down ... is it possible to do the same with C:\Users\user\Git\projectA\projectA if your based at the C:\Users\user\Git level?

Comment: Hi, to be able to go into C:\Users\user\Git\ProjectA\ProjectA then pull develop, the do a mvn clean install, then navigate back to C:\Users\user\Git and do the same for the other projects.

Comment: See update in answer please. but let me know if the parent/child will have the same names always please.

Comment: Yeah the parent name will be the same as the child name

Comment: It keeps saying "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git" when I access the folder directly, I get no issue. Any ideas why it may do this?

Comment: It seems its looking at the wrong direction for the POM file... I get this error also below the one above......

The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users\user\Git). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. ->

Comment: One last question, is there any way to specific the order in which it does it? I.e... I want to run projectB, then projectC, then projectA... it doesnt have to be looped either...

Comment: you would need to either run a specific for loop and use a array style update, or you would need to create some sort order. the problem here is that your projects could be called anything and can have many different projects, so it can become tedious.

Comment: Edited, see bottom 2 examples of answer.

Answer (score 0):

In a batch file, you could do something like :

```
for /D %s in (.\*) do
    cd %s
    git checkout develop
    mvn clean install
    cd ..
```

Comment: In a batch file you need to double on the `%`. Also, you will get syntax errors with this script because you did not double quote `(".\*")` and you need to parentesize the loop as it will also cause syntax errors.